# Is there a way to adjust brightness for only a single window?

Tags: brightness, window, window-manager

I need to make an app brighte. The app has no brightness adjustment and I would like make it appearance brighter, but I don't want to increase the brightness of the rest of the screen. How can I do this?

Comment: No, you can't. There's a single backlight controller for the whole screen.

Comment: @vidarlo: I disagree. It's entirely possible for the window manager to apply filters to individual windows to make them appear brighter or darker than others. You just need a capable windows manager and a suitable control interface. Both Compiz and Gnome Shell are such WMs if one takes extensions into account.

Comment: @DavidFoerster *Make them appear* in relation to the rest, yes.

Comment: @vidarlo: See “I would like make it appearance brighter, but I don't want to increase the brightness of the rest of the screen.”

Comment: @DavidFoerster I realise now that I missed that interpretation of it. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to clarify which Ubuntu release and desktop environment and/or window manager you use (e. g. Unity/Compiz, Gnome Shell/Mutter, KDE/KWin)? If you're unsure the output of `lsb_release -a` and `echo "$SESSION" "$SESSIONTYPE" "$DESKTOP_SESSION"` will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this (Ubuntu 16.04) using [CompizConfig Settings Manager][1]. Just go to Accessibility > Opacity, Brightness and Saturation > Brightness tab. From there you can add a new Window Specific Setting. Use the "grab" button to filter out the specific window you want to apply the new configuration to.

In my case, I wanted to reduce the brightness, so it was straightforward, just put a "Window Value" less than a 100. Of course, you can only apply up to 100% of the maximum brightness of your monitor. So, if you want to *increase* the brightness of a single window, you need to increase the overall brightness of the monitor, and then reduce the brightness of all windows except the filtered one. There's an "invert" button for that.

[image: See the attached image for an example result]

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't adjust the brightness/contrast/gamma of a specific window. What you CAN do if you have multiple screens is adjust the screens separately.

`xrandr`can do this on a screen by screen basis. The command structure is `xrandr --output displayname --brightness brightness`
where displayname is the connected display that you have chosen from the list that you get with the command `xrandr -q | grep " connected"`and brightness is a value of your choosing (1 being the default). Values above 2 will wash things out to the point of being virtually unreadable, and values of .1 or below aren't recommended either. Your mileage may vary somewhat depending on the darkness or brightness of your theme. Smaller adjustments are preferable until you get a sense of the extents you are looking for.